# Efficient way to calculate mean for huge data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have an output from previous simulation where it has 32872 row and 1000 column. the row represents daily data for 90 years while the column represents different data sets for 90 years. What i want to do is calculate the mean and standard deviation for every year separately. For example what i am doing is :

```
%for year 1
a=mean2(RAINFALL(1:365,:));
b=std2(RAINFALL(1:365,:));

%for year 2
a=mean2(RAINFALL(366:730,:));
b=std2(RAINFALL(366:730,:));
.
.
.
.
%for year 90
a=mean2(RAINFALL(32508:32872,:));
b=std2(RAINFALL(32508:32872,:));
```

What i did was i calculate manually each year so i have to do it manually for about 90 times. the problem is i have about 100 of data sets like this. Is there anyway that i can perform this via automatically or using loop or other any function in MATLAB to simplify this process and store the output data in one matrix such as:

[image]

so that i don't have to do it manually? I am new to MATLAB programming and hope that experts in MATLAB can suggest me idea how to solve this efficiently. i really appreciate your help because this is for my masters dissertation project. 
 Thank You

Comment: Which is the first year? This information is necessary to know the number of days of each year.

Comment: @DanielF.the first year is going to be year 2010 if that's what you asked.

Comment: Is the first value for January 1, 2010?

Comment: @craigim yes it is, 1 January 2010 and last data will be 31 DEC 2099.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `for` loop may help you -

```
R = rand(32872,90); % replace this with your rainfall data
startyear = 2010; % according to your comments

% generate array indices
nod = 365*ones(90,1) ... % number of days in each year
    +(mod((startyear:(startyear+89))',4)==0);
ind(:,2) = cumsum(nod);
ind(:,1) = [0; ind(1:end-1,2)]+1;

% find stats
a = zeros(90,1);
b = zeros(90,1);
for ii = 1:90
    yeardata = R(ind(ii,1):ind(ii,2),:);
    a(ii) = mean2(yeardata);
    b(ii) = std2(yeardata);
end
```

Note that the tricky point here is to handle the leap years properly.

If you don't have Image Processing Toolbox, which includes `mean2` and `std2`, then

```
    a(ii) = mean(yeardata(:));
    b(ii) = std(yeardata(:));
```

Comment: the first year is going to be year 2010. If i use mean it will give only mean each column but when i use mean2 it gives me mean of total 1000 column which that i want.

Comment: So you want to find one single number which is the average/std of `365x1000` numbers?

Comment: yes exactly. if im using 2010 as my first year do i have to change anything to the code that you provide?

Comment: I've updated my answer; see edit. Seriously, `mean2` and `std2` are used for image processing, and are only included in the image processing toolbox. No harm to use them if you like, but I would suggest `mean(mean(yeardata))`.

Comment: If you just want the mean of everything, save a call to `mean` with `mean(yeardata(:))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot yvon, @craigim , im testing the code right know, it seems works fine when using mean2/std2 but if i use mean(yeardata(:)) it gives an error.

Comment: @SABER So what's the error? I didn't get any :( Probably it's because you saw and used my old code, which was incorrect. Try again with `mean(yeardata(:))` it shouldn't give any problem. PS. If your error is reproducible, I shall leave my answer open to edit for anyone who see this, as I'm running out of my time.

Comment: Sorry man, its my mistake, the code works fine. @craigim You guys saved my precious time. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

To pick out the years, I think it is safest to take advantage of MATLAB's date functions, which already know all the rules for leap years.

```
data = rand(32872,100); % replace with your data matrix

[nDays,nData] = size(data);

% let MATLAB construct the vector of dates and worry about things like leap
% year.
dayFirst = datenum(2010,1,1);

dayStamp = dayFirst:(dayFirst + nDays - 1);
dayVec = datevec(dayStamp);

year = dayVec(:,1);

uniqueYear = unique(year);

K = length(uniqueYear);

a = nan(1,K);
b = nan(1,K);

for k = 1:K
   % use logical indexing to pick out the year
   currentYear = year == uniqueYear(k);
   a(k) = mean2(data(currentYear,:));
   b(k) = std2(data(currentYear,:));
end
```

The advantage of this method is that it is flexible. If you ever have a data set that doesn't start at January 1, or doesn't end on December 31, you don't have to figure out the indexing. MATLAB just does it for you. The other advantage is that you already then have an ordered list of the years if you want to subsequently call something like

```
errorbar(uniqueYear,a,b)
```

Comment: is it possible that calculation sum of the data sets for every year can be done using this code? for simplicity row 1-365 is the first year and column 1-1000 is data sets for the year, what i want is sum(1:365) for every column so the answer is going to be 1000 column with 1 row. i tried to manipulate the code above but i couldn't succeed and error occurred. I will be very thankful if you could help me with this too.

Answer (score 0):

For loop implementation:

```
for i=365:365:32872
  a=mean2(RAINFALL(i:i+365-1,:));
  b=std2(RAINFALL(i:i+365-1,:));
end
```

Comment: I got Index exceeds matrix dimensions error, "a=mean2(RAINFALL(i:i+365-1,:));
for your information im using 2010 as my first year.