# Select max value from huge matrix of 30 years daily data

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Lets say i have daily data for 30 years of period in a matrix. To make it simple just assume it has only 1 column and 10957 row indicates the days for 30 years. The year start in 2010. I want to find the max value for every year so that the output will be 1 column and 30 rows. Is there any automated way to program it in Matlab? currently im doing it manually where what i did was:

```
%for the first year
  max(RAINFALL(1:365);
.
.
%for the 30th of year
  max(RAINFALL(10593:10957);
```

It is exhausting to do it manually and i have quite few of same data sets. I used the code below to calculate mean and standard deviation for the 30 years. I tried modified the code to work for my task above but i couldn't succeed. Hope anyone can modify the code or suggest new way to me.

```
data = rand(32872,100); % replace with your data matrix

[nDays,nData] = size(data);

% let MATLAB construct the vector of dates and worry about things like leap
% year.
dayFirst = datenum(2010,1,1);

dayStamp = dayFirst:(dayFirst + nDays - 1);
dayVec = datevec(dayStamp);

year = dayVec(:,1);

uniqueYear = unique(year);

K = length(uniqueYear);

a = nan(1,K);
b = nan(1,K);

for k = 1:K
   % use logical indexing to pick out the year
   currentYear = year == uniqueYear(k);
   a(k) = mean2(data(currentYear,:));
   b(k) = std2(data(currentYear,:));
end
```

Comment: I think the only thing you need to add is `c = nan(1,K);` and `c(k) = max(max(data(currentYear,:)));` inside the loop. I still remember it's rayryeng's code.

Comment: 30 years' _data_ starting at 2010?

Comment: I was wrong. It was craigim's. Sorry if you see this, @craigim. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25123581/3839249

Comment: @LuisMendo yes starts on 1 jan 2010

Comment: So... you have daily rainfall data for all those years in the future? :-)

Comment: @Yvon, yeah its craigims code...:)

Comment: @LuisMendo, yes i have. Its just prediction..:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible approach:

1. Create a column containing the year of each data value, using [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) and [`datevec`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/datevec.html) to take care of leap years.
2. Find the maximum for each year, with [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html).

Code:

```
%// Example data: 
RAINFALL = rand(10957,1); %// one column
start_year = 2010;        %// data starts on January 1st of this year

%// Computations:
[year, ~] = datevec(datenum(start_year,1,1) + (0:size(RAINFALL,1)-1)); %// step 1
result = accumarray(year.'-start_year+1, RAINFALL.', [], @max);        %// step 2
```

As a bonus: if you change `@max` in step 2 by either `@mean` or `@std`, guess what you get... much simpler than your code.

Answer (score 1):

This may help You:

```
RAINFALL = rand(1,10957); % - Your data here

firstYear = 2010;
numberOfYears = 4;
cum = 0; % - cumulative factor
yearlyData = zeros(1,numberOfYears); % - this isnt really necessary

for i = 1 : numberOfYears
    yearLength = datenum(firstYear+i,1,1) - datenum(firstYear + i - 1,1,1);
    yearlyData(i) = max(RAINFALL(1 + cum : yearLength + cum));
    cum = cum + yearLength;
end
```